# Dropdown created in foreach loop blade not returning data to controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a form creating dynamic dropdowns depending on the number of items in the array $ecommerce_categories

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'categories.store', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'category_form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

{{ Form::token() }}


@foreach ($ecommerce_categories as $ecommerce_category)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $ecommerce_category->name }} </td>
        <td> {!! Form::select('id', $final_categories, null, ['placeholder' => 'Selecione uma categoria','class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>

    </tr>
@endforeach

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The fields are created but the data is not passing to the controller.
When I press the submit button I only get this as the data for the form:

```
( [_token] => x2IAExFVNBwkrYSU0faV9GpVEUUjMDNuC3KFaZRk [id] =>)
```

It should be an id for each dropdown created, but it's retuning an empty field.

This is how I'm trying to get the data in the controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $category = $this->categoryRepository->create($input);

    Flash::success('Category saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('categories.index'));
}
```

When I remove the dropdown fields from the for loop, it works perfectly:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'categories.store', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'category_form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

{{ Form::token() }}

{!! Form::select('id', $final_categories, null, ['placeholder' => 'Selecione uma categoria','class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>


{!! Form::close() !!}
```

What is wrong with the for loop?

Comment: The name must be unique for post the data ... try to chenge the name as unique inside the loop...

Comment: How can I create a name for each field created by the  loop?

Comment: {!! Form::select('id$ecommerce_category->ur_id', $final_categories, null, ['placeholder' => 'Selecione uma categoria','class' => 'form-control']) !!}